# Automation Testing for MPS applications

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, mps

Does anyone using automation testing tool for Jetbrain's MPS based application.
If yes can you please share the tools with me.
Or else if you can help me to choose one would be great

I have tested with the tools like Sikuli, AutiIT & Automa. But not all solve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains MPS is about creating languages and extensions and it is a very generic tool, so it means that there is not one single way to tests Jetbrains MPS applications.

MPS comes with:

- languages to test your languages (for example the typesystem or autocompletion)
- languages to test Java code (because Java has been implemented for the MPS platform)

If you build you own language using MPS you can then build also the concepts for testing your language.

Comment: Why not using a images based testing solution like sikuli or Automa? Though they are not that effective